# WPF control template control nesting vs Grid

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I'm writing custom control templates for WPF and using default control templates as starter.

When content presenter needs to have some background or foreground or outer border, it is often combined with `Border` control where color properties are set. I found two approaches used in default templates (published on MSDN):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ControlType}">
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
        <ContentPresenter/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This would place some background behind content presenter. However, I can get rid of `Grid` and place content presenter inside border:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ControlType}">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ContentPresenter/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Same behavior, minus Grid control. I tend to use 2nd approach just because I get rid of extra control (especially `Grid` which is computationally somewhat expensive). Are they equivalent? Or I'm missing something and 2nd approach has some drawbacks?

Comment: They are different... and you are right to go for the second approach...

In the second, you encompass the contentPresenter INSIDE the border. That means, when the content presenter grows, it will will be within or inside the margins of the border and the the background will be applied to it...

The same can not be said about the first... unless the horizontal and vertical alignment of the border is set to STRETCH.... In that case, you might as well just set the background of the grid to Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"

Comment: `The same can not be said about the first...` -- interesting comment. But if content presenter grows, outer grid (in first example) would grow as well and visually should not be any difference? Setting background on a grid is ok too, but would require a border when I need a border around presenter and face same dilemma.

Comment: I'm asking this, because I often pick default templates from MSDN and then tweak to my needs and MSDN uses `Grid` all around. for example, `HeaderedContentControl`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol.headertemplate?view=windowsdesktop-8.0, so maybe there is a reason behind this I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are *not* equivalent.

For example, the only part of a border which will be detected when hit testing is the borderlines themselves unless the border has a background (transparent is acceptable here), or hit testable content.

If we added a trigger to `Border` to react to `IsMouseOver` when `true` then if the `ContentPresenter` is outside of the `Border` it will not trigger regardless of the `ContentPresenter` content. If the `ContentPresenter` is inside of the `Border` then providing the `ContentPresenter` content is both filling the region where the mouse cursor is hovering over, and is hit testable, then it will trigger. This scenario assumes we are not setting a background.

This is the only difference that springs to mind, and it's what I would consider a minor one. I assume there are more, though I doubt anyone will/has done a deep dive into them.

Furthermore this assumes we modify the `Border` to add said trigger. If we are talking about any differences without modification of the original code, then I can't give you a concrete answer here - I'd suspect there to be none, though.

I have assumed we are not modifying any of the `Border` properties. Though, if we were to do this, then adding a `BorderThickness` which is greater than 0 would be a stand out difference as the content in the non nested version would have the potential to overlap the borderline.

Comment: Your last paragraph makes a lot of sense! I totally missed this point.